# How to sort items by date in tableview Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, swift3

So in my app, users can create expenses and store and view them in a per month basis. Currently, all my expense appear in the order I add them, but I want them to appear in the order of dates and I also want to have a tableviewheader with the dates so it groups the expenses together. I tried this code in my viewdidLoad.

```
for expense in monthlyExpenses{
        if let dateString = expense.modificationDate?.convertToString(){
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
        let finalDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
        if let finalDate = finalDate{
            let dateString2 = finalDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
            if self.toDoList[dateString2] == nil {
                self.toDoList[dateString2] = [expense.name!]
            }
            else {
                self.toDoList[dateString2]?.append(expense.name!)
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

and then tried this code in my tableviewheader section, however get a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    let dateDouble = self.sortedSections[section]

    let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: dateDouble)

    let dateformatter = DateFormatter()

    dateformatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium

    dateformatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none

    return dateformatter.string(from: date)

}
```

Each expense is an individual object that is stored in core data and has properties such as name, amount, modification date and etc. I want them to be sorted by modification Date. How will I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar, But I am using a library that already has xib and methods to adjust everything. Here is just a small help from my side.

You can prepare one xib to show dates and data in tableView. Here, you can hide the row if next date is same as previous date and show whenever the date changes. 
To show data according to dates you can do something like this (***If data is added according to dates***)

```
let expenses = [ExpensesClass]()

// in `cellForItemAt indexPath`

let expense = expenses[indexPath.row]
    let date = expense.date
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date! as Date)

. . . . . . 

if indexPath.row > 0 {
        let previousExpensesData = expenses[indexPath.row - 1].date  
        let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: expense.date) // Do not add above 'date' value here, you might get some garbage value. I know the code is redundant. You can adjust that.
        let previousDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: expenses[indexPath.row - 1].date)
            if day == previousDay {
                cell.dateTitle.text = ""
            } else {
                  cell.dateTitle.text = dateString
            }
    }else{
        cell.dateTitle.text = dateString
        print("Cannot return previous Message Index...\n\n")
    }
```

You can adjust height in this method -> `func tableView(UITableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath).`

I am not sure about this method -> `func tableView(UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection: Int)` . You can try it in this method as well if the above one doesn't work for you and adjust the height accordingly in -> `func tableView(UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection: Int)`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
     heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    let expense = expenses[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.row > 0{
        let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: expense.date)
        let previousDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: expense[indexPath.row - 1].date) 
        if day == previousDay {
            return 0.0
        }else{
             return 20.0
        }
    }
    return 20.0
}
```

Comment: Awesome thinking! That was really clever never thought you could do it that way instead of introducing sections, just creating a label for it. Thanks I've been trying to do this for hours!!

Comment: @A.G Hey... I am so glad it helped...Thanks... Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

**1. Create a dictionary which contains date as a key and array of orders modified or placed on that as value.**

var orderDictionary[Date:[Order]?] = [:]

```
for order in yourOrders {
  
  var orders = orderDictionary[order.modificationDate] ?? []
  
  if orders.count == 0 {
     orderDictionary[order.modificationDate] = [order]
  } else {
     orders.append(order)
     orderDictionary[order.modificationDate] = orders
  }
}
```

**2. Sort key array from dictionary.**

`let dateArray = orderDictionary.keys`

`dateArray.sort { $0 < $1 }`

*Change compare condition based on your requirement like whether you want it in ascending or in descending order.*

**3. In `func tableView(UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection: Int)` write**

`return dateArray[section]` or format date as you want.

**4. In `numberOfRowsForSection` write**

`return orderDictionary[dateArray[section]].count`

**5. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` write**

`let order = orderDictionary[dateArray[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row]`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however I keep getting an error that since orders is a let, it's not mutable and therefore you can't append anything to it.

Comment: Also what about the numberOfRowsInSection function?

Comment: @A.G I have updated the answer as per your comment check it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have a couple of questions however there just one more problem. Where should I do the second step as if I do it in the viewdidload, then I can't use dataArray in any other method. Also, for steps 2 and 3, since indexPath is not a parameter, I'm assuming you just mean to create a new IndexPath() and make it equal to indexPath?

Comment: @A.G declare **dateArray** as class level object. like `var dateArray = [Date]() ` and for **3 point i have updated answer.** Wherever I have written IndexPath.section there I meant pass section index as parameter.

Comment: I just have this last error which is quite strange which is for step 2 in the let dateArray = orderDictionary.keys. As soon as I use var dateArray = [Date](), I get an error saying

**Cannot assign value of type 'LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<NSDate, [Expense]?>, NSDate>' (aka 'LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<NSDate, Optional<Array<Expense>>>, NSDate>') to type '[NSDate]'**

Comment: Declare dateArray like this `var dateArray = [NSDate]()`

Comment: Yep that's what I did in the first place, but I still got the same error.